# Facebook Firebase Auth and Facebook Graph API with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Facebook Firebase Auth to authanticate users to my application (front end). I need to get the birthday of the authenticated user.

Here is what I do when I click my  "Sign in with Facebook" Button:

```
const signUpWithFacebook = async () => {
    try {

        let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
        provider.addScope("user_birthday");
        var result = await authAPI.signInWithProvider(provider)
        
        console.log(result.user); // user is printed and I have access to the access_token
        

        var graphUrl =
            "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token=" +
            result.credential.accessToken;

        var user = await fetch(graphUrl); // Here I get a CORS error response
        
        console.log(user );

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

I am testing using a facebook test account created via the my facebook app.

I have put "localhost" into App Domains settings of my facebook app.

Why do I get a CORS error and how to solve this ?
Thank you.

**UPDATE** :

I get this response from the `await fetch(graphUrl)` line :

```
{
    body: ReadableStream
    bodyUsed: false
    headers: Headers {}
    ok: true
    redirected: false
    status: 200
    statusText: ""
    type: "cors"
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token=<my-access-token>"
}
```

Comment: The endpoint is clearly CORS-enabled, it sends `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the response. Please quote the _exact_ error message you are getting.

Comment: I have updated my post with the error you requested

Comment: What makes you think this was an error message?

Comment: I get this response on Chrome. On Firefox it just tells me there was a Cors error.

Comment: and it is not returning me the data I asked

Comment: Also, when I copy/paste `graphUrl` into a web browser, I get the data I need : a json containing the user with his birthday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I came up with a solution (partial)**

**The requests works when you load the Facebook SDK. Here is how to do it :**

1. **Load Facebook SDK**

Add a useEffect function to load the fb sdk so that window.FB is defined
*(this can be copy/paste, you just have to change your appId)* :

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        window.FB.init({
            appId: "<your_app_id>",
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: "v9.0",
        });
    }.bind(this);

    // Load the SDK asynchronously --- DOESNT WORK WITH FIREFOX : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226498
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
            fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
}, []);
```

2. **Use Firebase FB Auth function get your access token**

Using firebase built-in functionnality will make firebase store the user in your firebase app.

```
const signUpWithFacebook = async () => {
        try {
            let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
            provider.addScope("user_birthday");
            var firebaseFBAuth = await authAPI.signInWithProvider(provider);

            if (window.FB) {
                window.FB.api(
                    "/me",
                    "get",
                    {
                        access_token: firebaseFBAuth.credential.accessToken,
                        fields: "birthday",
                    },
                    (resp) => {
                        console.log(resp.birthday); // Whe have the user birthday !
                    }
                );
            } else {
                // facebook sdk couldn't be loaded : authenticating with minimum infos
                console.log(firebaseFBAuth.user.displayName);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
};
```

And you're all set, you have access to the Facebook Graph Api with a Facebook user authenticated though Firebase.

3. **Problem with Firefox**

As you can see in the comment in my first snippet, Firefox doesn't load the Facebook SDK script. Firefox enables tracking protection by default and the Facebook SDK script is recognized as a tracker. This is why in my second snippet I test whether window.FB is initialized.
If it is not, then I don't try to get more information about the user. I just create the user with the infos we have: displayName and email. Which are enough to create an account.

**If anyone manages to get this working with Firefox I'd be happy to know how.**